# How to make Multilanguage TabBarItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I need to change title of TabBarItem by pulling string from language1.plist or language2.plist.
Language switcher is based on button press. Language switcher is doing ok, but I just can`t change title of TabBarItem

FirstMenuController.m

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    // LOADING ACTIVE LANGUAGE
    AppDelegate* appdelegat = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    deflanguage = appdelegat.activeLangunage;

    // Getting TabBarItem title FROM plist
    NSString* menuitem1 = [deflanguage objectForKey:kTabBarItem1];

    [self.tabBarItem initWithTitle: menuitem1];

    //THIS IS WHAT I TRY - NOT WORKING
    // self.tabBarController.tabBarItem.title = menuitem1;

    // self.tabBarItem.title = menuitem1;

    // UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    // UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
    // UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    // tabBarItem1.title = @"First"

    NSLog(menuitem1);
}
```

In console from NSLog I get data from plist for (menuitem1): "HomeDE".

When I go back to language screen and click on language2 button, in next screen, in console I get "HomeFR". So that part is working, but I don`t know how to put that in TabBarItem title... :-(

Thank`s in advance

Answer (score 0):

Set the title property on each **view controller** to its localized title.
I mean the view controllers that the tab bar controller is switching between, not the tab bar controller itself.  You generally do that in the init method for each view controller.

Comment: It`s not reflecting on first when I change. Do I need to do localization in all TabBarItem`s ViewControllers so it could work..?

Comment: The code that is shown in question is from First TabBarItem ViewController